# Why did I lose my field upgrade?

Tags: battlefield-4

I see this message across my screen from time to time stating (roughly): You have lost your service field upgrade.

I know that field upgrades are given to squads from their commander, but why did I lose it?  Did my commander demote our squad?  Or do I have to accept the field upgrade as Squad Leader?

Comment: Oh didnt see that one.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If everyone in your squad is wiped (all killed and waiting to respawn) then you lose your field upgrade score.

This is why it's important to stay alive when the message pops up indicating you're the last member alive in the squad.